# Reason for perpetual dynamic DNS updates?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, bind, bonjour, dynamic-dns

I'm using dynamic DNS (the "adult" version from RFC 2136, not à la DynDNS), and for a while now I've been seeing my laptops with MacOS 10.6.x churning out updates about every 10 seconds. And seemingly redundant updates at that, as the IP is more or less stable (consumer broadband). I don't remember seeing that frequency in the (distant...) past.

The lowest time-to-live that MacOS pushes on the entries is 2 minutes, so I have no clue what's going on.

```
...
Jan 12 13:17:18 lambda named[18683]: info: client 84.208.X.X#48715: updating zone 'dynamic.foldr.org/IN': deleting rrset at 'rCosinus._afpovertcp._tcp.dynamic.foldr.org' SRV
Jan 12 13:17:18 lambda named[18683]: info: client 84.208.X.X#48715: updating zone 'dynamic.foldr.org/IN': adding an RR at 'rCosinus._afpovertcp._tcp.dynamic.foldr.org' SRV
Jan 12 13:17:26 lambda named[18683]: info: client 84.208.X.X#48715: updating zone 'dynamic.foldr.org/IN': deleting rrset at 'rcosinus.dynamic.foldr.org' AAAA
...
```

Additionally, I can't find out what triggers the updates on the laptop-side. Is this a known problem, and how would I go about debugging it? One of the machines is freshly purchased and installed. The only "major" change was installation of the [Miredo](http://www.deepdarc.com/miredo-osx/) client for IPv6/Teredo, but even disabling it didn't make a change (except that AAAA records are no longer published).

(Crossposted to the [Apple exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7513/3197)).

Comment: You might want to ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Josh Thanks, I'm just hoping to have a better shot here since this is a problem with infrastructure more commonly found on the enterprise-level.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I wasn't suggesting you should close this question. Just that you might want to cross-post it. I'd answer if I had any experience with what you're doing... I run BIND on a G4, but only as a local caching nameserver :-/

Comment: (If you do cross-post, be sure to link the two together and, as soon as you get an answer on one, post the answer to the others and accept it so they don't remain open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, must have been something transient: I noticed that the SOA didn't change, and after a zone freeze/thaw, the problem suddenly disappeared. Looks like BIND might have had a hick-up.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your Apple equipment using Dynamic DNS to announce zeroconf features (also known as Bonjour), it's pretty common that these features get registered and deregistered (I'm experiencing the same at home using dynamic DNS).

You can also reduce debugging on the DNS config if you wish to avoid huge log files :)

Comment: Um, in 5 second intervals, on an idle machine? I don't remember seeing earlier MacOS versions doing this. Either someone is really registering something repeatedly, then I'd like to find out which service it is, so that I can disable it. Or it is not and Bonjour decides this by itself, in which case I'd count this as a big.

Comment: To go with the meme: imagine what "a beowulf cluster of these" would do to the network/DNS server.

Comment: @mad_vs I've seen flashes of this happen on my DNS too, not constant though, maybe the machine is trying and failing to register the DNS name for the service?

Comment: Nope, everything looking dandy on the server-side (the above log messages only happen when things are fine, if e.g. the user/password would be wrong, it'd tell me).